# PHP MS SQL Update return success but no update in database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ajax, sqlsrv

I am trying to update a row in my database via AJAX. `$stmt_aufschlag` returns true, but no updates in the database are made.
Executing the query directly in SQL Management Studio works fine.

Once I define a second variable with `sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_aufschlag)` it works and the rows are updating. This is weird because I have several functions where the update query works fine with a single `sqlsrv_query` and I have another case where I have so assign `sqlsrv_query` twice.
Am I missing some arguements?

Here's my PHP code:

```
$serverName = "server2020";

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Auftragsmanagement", 'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=> true, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
function save_aufschlag($conn){
        $artikel = $_POST['artikel'];
        $preisgruppe = $_POST['preisgruppe'];
        $aufschlag = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $_POST['aufschlag']));
        $sql_aufschlag = "UPDATE dbo.Artikel SET Kalkulation_AufschlagPG$preisgruppe = $aufschlag WHERE id = '$artikel'";
        $stmt_aufschlag = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_aufschlag);
        $test = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_aufschlag);
        if($stmt_aufschlag){
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200, "sql"=>$sql_aufschlag));
        } 
        else if($stmt_aufschlag === false){
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201, "error"=>print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true), "sql"=>$sql_aufschlag));
        }
    }
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Are you sure it does that?? Because all you're doing is just running the exact same query twice, so it should produce the same result each time.

Comment: Why are you using same config again???

Comment: See if this comment helps: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#122275

Comment: As @SalmanA suggested, try to place `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your statement. Or execute `while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt_$stmt_aufschlag) != null){};` after the first `sqlsrv_query()` call to clean the output buffer.

Comment: Do you have other functions making use of the same `$conn` variable? Possibly other functions are leaving the connection in a funky state before `save_aufschlag` gets a crack at it so the first time you execute it the update query is never applied to the database. You should always create a new connection before issuing a query, and close the connection immediately afterwards. In most decent libraries closing a connection doesn't actually close it - it will return it to a connection pool, resetting the connection to a known state when the next caller needs one.

Comment: @Zhorov Thats the solution, thank you!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Only this function is using `$conn`, the previous function is not being called at this ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Salman A and @Zhorov!

`SET NOUCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of the SQL Query is the solution.

Comment: I would recommend PHP PDO with SQL server driver instead. Using it for more than 5 years, no issues.