# SQL (sqlsrv) Cursor not finishing when execute from PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

The SQL code below works great in MSSQL but when called via php it only outputs roughly half the results. I have tried placing this in a stored procedure and executing from php but that produces the same result as well.

It should be inserting 150 rows, but I am getting only 77, sometimes 78, but it is always one of those two numbers, which leads me to believe its stopping close to half way every time...

````
error_reporting(0);   //turn off error reporting

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['id']) {

require('../config.php');

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$password);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $host, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "INSERT INTO [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers] (offertype)
Select distinct(offertype) from [RP].[dbo].[Offers] t2
where convert(date,[RedeemedDate]) >= convert(date,getdate()-30)
and not exists (Select distinct(offertype) from [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers] t1 where t1.OfferType = t2.offertype )

truncate table [RP].[dbo].[RP_Last30days]

DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @OfferType NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR
Declare @counter int
Declare @nextDate as Date

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers].ID,
       [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers].OfferType
FROM   [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers]


OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @id, @OfferType
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --print @offertype


    Set @counter = 1
    WHILE (@counter < 31 ) 
    begin
    Set @nextDate = convert(varchar,getdate() -30 + @counter,101)
    insert into [RP].[dbo].[Last30Days] ([Date],[OfferType])
    Select Convert(varchar,@nextDate,101), @OfferType
    Set @counter = @counter + 1
    END


    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @id, @OfferType
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid";

$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
if ($stmt === False) {
    echo "Faild to worked!";
} else {
   // echo "Should have worked... ";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

}

?>```
````

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ and is a part of `select distinct`. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `Select distinct offertype from...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Done, and thank you, but unrelated to the posted issue. @jarlh

Comment: See if this comment on php docs applies to you: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#122275

Comment: @SalmanA the comment in your link worked! To be specific, I needed to add SET NOCOUNT ON to the top of the script as well as using sqlsrv_prepare and sqlsrv_execute in place of sqlsrv_query.  Thank you!

Comment: This is the [second time this week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351823/php-ms-sql-update-return-success-but-no-update-in-database) the comment helped.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to remove that unnecessary cursor, too. You don't need to loop this. You can use a top(30) row_number *-1 to generate your 30 dates as a CTE, then use a CROSS JOIN with RP_UniqueOffers to populate all the rows as a single insert.
Let me know if you want to see an example.

Comment: There are a number of side issues with your code as it stands: Entirely lacking `try` `finally` in order to close the connection and statement objects. `DISTINCT` is not a function and does not need brackets, it operates over the whole resultset and brackets just confuses people. `where convert(date,[RedeemedDate]) >= convert(date,getdate()-30)` is not sarge-able (cannot use indexes), also dates are not supposed to be used with arithmetic, instead use `where RedeemedDate >= DATEADD(day, -30, CONVERT(date, getdate())) AND RedeemedDate < DATEADD(day, -29, CONVERT(date, getdate()))`. ......

Comment: ..... The whole `WHILE` loop and cursor shebang is completely pointless and a performance-killer: you could just use a cross-join to a `VALUES` clause of 31 rows. `DISTINCT` in an `EXISTS` subquery makes no sense, and may cause performance issues. For a batch which returns no results, `SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED` option is almost certainly going to be the fastest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @SalmanA

I needed to add SET NOCOUNT ON to the top of the script as well as using sqlsrv_prepare and sqlsrv_execute in place of sqlsrv_query.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For your consideration: lose the cursor. This can be set-based.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers] (offertype)
Select distinct(offertype) from [RP].[dbo].[Offers] t2
where convert(date,[RedeemedDate]) >= convert(date,getdate()-30)
and not exists (Select distinct(offertype) from [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers] t1 where t1.OfferType = t2.offertype )

truncate table [RP].[dbo].[RP_Last30days];

WITH ThirtyDays
AS (
   SELECT top(30)
          DATEADD(DAY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id)*-1,GETDATE()) as nextDate
     FROM sys.columns
)
INSERT [RP].[dbo].[Last30Days] ([Date],[OfferType])
SELECT CONVERT(char(10),ThirtyDays.nextDate,101)
     , RP_UniqueOffers.OfferType
  from [RP].[dbo].[RP_UniqueOffers]
CROSS JOIN ThirtyDays;
";
```

Comment: Instead of messing about with system tables and `ROW_NUMBER`, why not just use a virtual table `SELECT DATEADD(day, -v.Day, GETDATE()) NextDate FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30) ) v(Day)`